# Ubuntu 19.04 doesn't use proxy

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, 19.04

I set up a proxy, but when checking ip using a browser, any site for checking ip shows my real ip address. Also, the request is not proxied when calling in the `terminal google-chrome -proxy-server = "http://<address>:<port>"`

Comment: Did you really type in the spaces?  You also appear to be missing the double dash.  The command should be something like `google-chrome-stable --proxy-server="http://<address>:<port>"`

Comment: Your variant doesn't work also

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when you run it?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1157278/edit) your question and copy and paste exactly what you are typing in and any errors that you are seeing.  I can only guess as to why it is not working without seeing what you see.

Comment: There is no http prefix for the proxy. It should be plain "localhost:8888" or similar